# Connection reset by peer or socket closed out of nothing

Tags: java, sockets, server

So far I've used this site whenever I encountered a problem and I've found solutions too, but this time I have no idea what's even happening.

I am working on a game that is based on a 1-vs-1-multiplayer-mode. So far i have created a server and my program with the client.

My server creates a new thread with a socket for every client that connects with the server and when the "New Game"-Button is pressed in the game, the thread searches for another thread that is looking for a new game right now and once it found him, creates a separate thread that sends a message to both threads to signal them that a game has started, which is then sent through their socket to the program which reacts accordingly.

Here is my code:

Thread:

```
    public void run() {

    try {

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ServerNachricht inputLine, outputLine;
        LabyrinthProtocol prot = new LabyrinthProtocol();


        while (socket.isConnected()) {
```

ServerNachricht is a class that consists of a type(int), a sender(player) and a message(String).
When the thread gets a new game message, the protocol changes the players status-value to "searching", then looks if another "searching" player exists and then changes both players values to "playing" and returns a new ServerNachricht of type Kampfbeginn with the found player as sender.
After the protocol returns the outputLine, this is what the thread does:

```
                    if (outputLine.getArt() == ServerNachricht.KAMPFBEGINN) {
                    System.out.println(outputLine.getSender().getSname()+" ist da");    
                    server.kampfbeginn(this, outputLine.getSender());
                }
```

The sysout just verifies that the protocol has actually found another player and is printing that players name to be sure. So far, this has always worked.
Here are the parts that call for a new game in the server:

```
    public void kampfbeginn(LabyrinthThread t, Spieler gegner) {
    KampfThread kampf = null;
    System.out.println(gegner.getSname()+" anerkannt");
    for(int i = 0;i<threads.size();i++){
        if(threads.get(i)!=null){
            System.out.println(threads.get(i).getSpieler().getSname());
            if(threads.get(i).getSpieler().getSname().equals(gegner.getSname())){
                LabyrinthThread gegnert = threads.get(i);
                kampf = new KampfThread(t,gegnert);
                t.setKampf(kampf);
                gegnert.setKampf(kampf);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code searches through every existing thread (the server stores them in a vector) and checks if that threads connected player is the player returned by the protocol. When the thread was found, both threads are then given to a newly created thread that stores both of them while also storing that new thread in both threads.
The new thread even verifies the connection with two sysouts:

```
    public KampfThread(LabyrinthThread spieler1, LabyrinthThread spieler2) {
    super();
    this.spieler1 = spieler1;
    this.spieler2 = spieler2;
    System.out.println(spieler1.getSpieler().getSname() + "ist drin");
    System.out.println(spieler2.getSpieler().getSname() + "ist drin");

}
```

which I also get every time.
After both connections are established, that thread sends a message to both threads so that they will notify their programs to start:

```
        case(ServerNachricht.KAMPFBEGINN):
        spieler1.ThreadNachricht(new ServerNachricht(ServerNachricht.KAMPFBEGINN,spieler2.getSpieler(),""));
        spieler2.ThreadNachricht(new ServerNachricht(ServerNachricht.KAMPFBEGINN,spieler1.getSpieler(),""));
        break;
```

which calls this method in the threads:

```
    public void ThreadNachricht(ServerNachricht s) {

    if(socket.isConnected()) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is that this works absolutely perfect about 80% of the time (so both programs go into the "game started" mode) but sometimes it just works for one or even neither program and the server gets either a
Connection reset by peer
or a
Socket closed
error in

```
    public void ThreadNachricht(ServerNachricht s) {

    if(socket.isConnected()) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in the out.writeObject(s); line. There is no line anywhere that closes anything (I've even taken out every single close() out of anywhere to make sure that nothing can interfere) and there seems to be no pattern at all to when it works and when it doesn't (and not working closes the servers and the programs clientsocket so the program is unable to work when that happens). Is there any way I can guarantee that my program works or is there any error I made? I am rather desperate because I couldn't even do major tests to find out a pattern since starting the program twice with exactly the same setup still causes it to work most of the time.

Edit: I literally just had a situation in which one player went into the new game mode while the other one stayed in the main menu (resulting in a Connection reset by peer: socket write error for the server) twice in a row before it worked the third time without any problems in the same run. So I searched with both players but only one went into the game screen (and the other one got the error). I then pressed back to go into the main menu and did the same again with the same result. When I tried for the third time, it worked and both players got into the game screen and started interacting with each other.

Comment: Just as a design comment, you probably have a very bugged road ahead of you with all those threads. You can do with much fewer: a `Worker` thread (to match waiting players) and maybe, according to what your server actually does, one for every game currently being played.

Comment: A worker thread sounds pretty nice but my server is doing more that just matching players. For example the thread is used for login or account operations too. Also the threads connect to the database for pretty much every relevant information. So I don't know if a worker thread would be able to handle everything, especially when it is forced to wait before matching players.

Comment: Hello there and Welcome to Stack overflow. I reverted your latest edit. Instead of editing the answer into the question (where it's just rather confusing) you should write an answer and accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a rather funny error I made: My server kept the threads stored in his vector even after their sockets disconnected. So logging in with an account that was already connected to the server before since its last restart (I use to keep the server running when I'm just testing cosmetic things) causes its

```
   for(int i = 0;i<threads.size();i++){
    if(threads.get(i)!=null){
        System.out.println(threads.get(i).getSpieler().getSname());
        if(threads.get(i).getSpieler().getSname().equals(gegner.getSname())){
```

loop to determine the thread for the other player to find an older and already closed thread and not the one the other player is connected to at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

- 'connection reset' usually means that your wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the peer: in other words, an application protocol error.
- 'socket closed' means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it.
- Neither of these comes 'out of nowhere'. Both indicate application bugs.
- `isConnected()` is not an appropriate test. It doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects. I'm not sure it becomes false even when *you* disconnect.

All this indicates nothing more than coding bugs. Post more of your code and I'll show you some more of them.